# how to capture web_cam image using python?

Tags: python

how to capture `web_cam` image using python`(raw python)` without using
 any library like `cv2` or pygame.

> it would be great if anybody know the trick how to capture image using
>   only `raw python`. advance thank you so much.

I tried using the `VideoCapture` extension, but that didn't work very well for me. But the problem is that it's a bit slow with resolutions `320x230`, and sometimes it returns None for no apparent reason.

Comment: Why you don't want to use libraries? Anyway, you can search inside pygame or cv2 libraries to study the raw code and build your custom functions.
https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python
https://github.com/pygame/

Comment: you can't capture image using only raw python. You need external modules like `cv2` or `PyGame`. I'm not sure but maybe `ffmpeg` can also read `web_cam`. And if you have problem with speed then you should first check if you have the same problem with other tools - maybe problem is camera, not Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need this:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

To Save image press space

Try This:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
    if not ret:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: okay alright! , can i open webcam silently?(without turning on light)

Answer (score 0):

by use Pygame 3.4

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqmSpJfN7OE

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

You can download "pygame‑1.9.2a0.win32‑py3.4.exe"

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480))
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img,"filename.jpg")
```